# Copy Data to Another Excel WorkBook Based on Criteria Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

We have a workbook called Refund Automation where we enter the daily transactions. We would like to extract all rows that contain the entry ‘Archieved’ and copy them to a ‘masterdata’ workbook. Also we would like to update our ‘masterdata’ workbook on a daily basis so that only ‘Archived of today’ are posted to the ‘masterData’ workbook.  Can any one please correct the code it says Variable not defined on  line 2

```
Sub myData()
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Cells(i, 24).Value = Date And Cells(i, 25).Value = “Done” Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 25)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E\Brm\By Ram Final.xlsm"
Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Double quotes instead of inverted  commas and its absolutely working fine .

```
Sub myData()
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Cells(i, 24).Value = Date And Cells(i, 25).Value = "Done" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 25)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\Brm\By Ram Final.xlsm"

Worksheets("DATA").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next i
End Sub
```